Need help with sharepoint project [I'm totally new with Sharepoint]
I'm currently doing an internship with a company (a 7-week internship) and the company has given me an internship project involving the use of Sharepoint.
The problem is that out of these 7 weeks I had to spend 4 in IT support to help the technicians. The problem is that I've still got 3 weeks of work experience left for my project, and I've hardly started yet. The situation is critical.
My internship subject is as follows: To create a portal for the company's web applications, in which elements would be displayed according to the active directory group of the user accessing the portal.
I've tried to read up on Sharepoint and Active Directory, but unfortunately, as I mentioned in the title, I'm totally new to Sharepoint and I don't really understand anything, even after watching Microsoft tutorials, try to use Microsoft Sharepoint Online Management shell etc. The company seems to use Sharepoint online but i'm not eaven sure of that :/
I've created a list where i put an web application name, link, image and authorized groups unfortunately i don't know how to sync them with the microsoft 365 active directory group and i'm lost.
This project seems insurmountable to me given the scope of Sharepoint and all the features present, I don't know where to turn.
I hope that some of you will be able to help me by giving me lines of research, leads, etc.
Thank you in advance and have a nice day.


Images for the the comment :




I think there are two concepts in SharePoint than can help you:

Audience targeting: by enabling audience targeting, specific content will be prioritized to specific audiences through SharePoint web parts, page libraries, and navigational links.

Item level permissions: it's a feature that allows users or groups to view specific items within a list.


How to Enable Item Level Permissions in SharePoint (Guide)
How to enable Item Level Permissions in SharePoint
Item level permission based on groups rather than user
Enable item level permissions in SharePoint | quick & efficient methods revealed!

Thank you for the answer, give me some time to take a closer look to audience targetting and i'll let you know if it's work in my case :D

I don't get sharepoint gui, like why do a little thing is so hard :(. For example i cannot add existing group on my site authorization. Like the office 365 groups would fit perfectly because these are active directory groups that i'm looking for. I've added some images to my original post for you to see. Thank you in advance for your answer.

SharePoint permissions are managed by SharePoint groups (built-in groups like Owners, Members and Visitors, but also custom groups). Within these groups, you can add users or groups (Microsoft 365 groups, Entra groups).
